# Mysql query for sum two table data by product wise

Tags: mysql, sql

If I use the below code the sum of sale and purchase product wise perfect but 5 NO product missing because no purchase only sale but I want to show all product. what-ever purchase or sale are zero.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity) AS sale
    FROM order_item group by product_id
) P
JOIN (
    SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity) AS purchase
    FROM pur_item
    group by product_id
) S
JOIN (
    SELECT product_id as Pid
    FROM product GROUP BY Pid
) I ON I.Pid = P.product_id AND S.product_id = P.product_id
```

[image]

If is use below code then result is like below. I don't know sum of sale and purchase is not perfect.

```
select p.product_id, sum(s.quantity) sale, sum(c.quantity) purchase
from product p
left join pur_item c on c.product_id = p.product_id
left join order_item s on s.product_id = p.product_id
where c.quantity is not null or s.quantity is not null
group by p.product_id
```

[image]

I want result for all item sum of product wise data what ever sale or purchase made.

Comment: I recommend not using the term "Sir" - they are many genders other than male on this site and even many males feel odd being addressed as Sir.

Comment: Could you please show us the schema?

Comment: Also its not appropriate to suggest any kind of urgency or importance on your questions. everyone who answers questions on here does so as a volunteer and its not OK to suggest or imply any kind of pressure for them to do so. So ask your question as best you can and if its a well asked question you'll most likely receive an answer in a timely fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking the correct approach in your first query but your `JOIN` conditions are wrong and you need to use `LEFT JOIN`s instead of `JOIN` to get products which have no purchases or no sales:

```
SELECT I.product_id, 
       COALESCE(S.sale, 0) AS sale, 
       COALESCE(P.purchase, 0) AS purchase
FROM Product I
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity) AS sale
    FROM order_item 
    GROUP BY product_id
) S ON S.product_id = I.product_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity) AS purchase
    FROM pur_item
    GROUP BY product_id
) P ON P.product_id = I.product_id
```

We also use `COALESCE` to convert `NULL` values (when a product has no purchases or sales) to `0`.

Comment: Dear sir, Nick Thanks a lot. you are very helpfully person and your code is perfect. Sir can you tell me, if i want to total sum of sale and purchase date wise. then what code needed. i am already made another table which content date. Thank you

Comment: @PapluDey you will probably need to join your date table to the `order_item` and `pur_item` tables. Without seeing all the structures it's hard to tell. I would recommend asking another question.

Comment: HI, nick sir, i need another help from you. I an developed an chart.js for my daily sale table from sql .every think works good but chart show all data  but i need last  15 days data as well. what can i do now.

Comment: @PapluDey I really recommend asking another question. Is there a reason you can't?